# Mocking framework for ASP.net 5.0 vnext class library project

Tags: asp.net, mocking

I have created a ASP.net `vnext` class library project in Visual Studio 2015. Now I want to test my project. So, I want to use mocking stuffs in my test project.
Here is my `project.json` file

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "xunit": "2.0.0-rc3-build2880",
        "xunit.runner.aspnet": "2.0.0-rc3-build52",
          "My project name with version",
           "Moq": "4.2.1502.911"     
    },

    "commands": { "test": "xunit.runner.aspnet" },

    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {             

            }
        }

    }
    }
```

But I am getting error `:Dependency Moq` with the Version 4.2.1502.911 could not be resolved.

I also tried different version of `Moq`, but results the same: `dependency error`.
Without Mock I can't move further in testing.

Any help?

Comment: I have this version : "Moq": "4.2.1502.0911",  and have these feeds in my package manager settings : https://nuget.org/api/v2/  and https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetrelease/ for the asp ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on comment, the error is incorrect package manager settings :

the correct feeds to use are : nuget.org/api/v2 and myget.org/F/aspnetrelease for the asp ones